# Convert a list with multiple elements into a dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, 3d, 2d

I tried to find a solution for this but I am not able to solve it. I have a list, with 7 elements, they are dataframes. Each of these elements have two columns. All I want to do is to have a single dataframe that contains all the columns from the list. I have attached two pictures, hopefully it explains better. About the picture, the list is on the left hand side and when I click on the first dataframe, the DataFrame editor on the right hands side opens. Each of the dataframes has two columns with 1000 data. I should end up with 14 columns with 1000 data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S8Zi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# list of dataframes
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7]

# concatenate the dataframes along the columns axis
result = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

Reference link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 1):

To create a single DataFrame that contains all the columns from a list of DataFrames, you can use the concat() function from the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

The axis parameter specifies which axis to concatenate along (0 for rows, 1 for columns).

Answer (score 0):

you can combine DataFrame objects horizontally along the x axis by passing in `axis=1` into `pandas.concat` function ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html))

```py
pd.concat(dataframe_list, axis=1)
```